# how to add gradient color to vector image in android and to use in bottom navigation view

Tags: android, gradient, bottomnavigationview

how to achieve this bottom navigation view in android with gradient color effect.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Incase you dont have gradient drawable, here is the example of primary_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

You need to make a selector for it, lets call it nav_item_background_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/primary_gradient" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Then you can add code below to your bottom navigation

> app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background_state"

Comment: Thanks Erwin Kurniawan i was able to achieve gradient overlay color but how to get gradient color vector icon and that top gradient color selected line??

Answer (score 0):

you can use gradient color in vector but drawable is not allowed

for using gradient color you have to create a file inside res/color folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:centerColor="#0000FF"
    android:endColor="#00FFFF"
    android:angle="145"
    android:startX="30"
    android:endX="70"
    android:startY="30"
    android:endY="70"
    android:type="linear"/>
```

and inside vector file use it as a normal color